# jquery getjson issue

Tags: jquery, json

this code works fine in script tag. But when i write this code in a function and call it anywhere, getjson doesnt work. i did not change anything, just put it in a function and code doesnt work.
Here is my code:

```
var searchUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" + "emre" + "&rpp=" + 5 + "&lang=en&callback=?";

$.getJSON(searchUrl, function(data) {
  var twitterList = $( "<ul />" );

  $.each( data.results, function( index, item ) {
    $( "<li />", { "text" : item.text } )
    .appendTo( twitterList );
  });

  $( "#output" ).fadeOut( "fast", function(){
    $( this ).empty()
    .append( twitterList )
    .fadeIn( "slow" );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var twitterURL = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" + "emre" + "&rpp=" + 5 + "&lang=en&callback=?";    
    myFunction(twitterURL);
  });

  function myFunction(twitterURL) {
    $.getJSON(twitterURL, function(data) {
      var twitterList = $( "<ul />" );

      $.each( data.results, function( index, item ) {
        $( "<li />", { "text" : item.text } )
        .appendTo( twitterList );
      });

      $( "#output" ).fadeOut( "fast", function() {
        $( this ).empty()
        .append( twitterList )
        .fadeIn( "slow" );
      });
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/JqGVt/)

**Function :**

```
  function searchThis(url){
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var twitterList = $( "<ul />" );

     $.each( data.results, function( index, item ) {
       $( "<li />", { "text" : item.text } )
       .appendTo( twitterList );
     });

     $( "#output" ).fadeOut( "fast", function(){
       $( this ).empty()
       .append( twitterList )
       .fadeIn( "slow" );
    });
  });
}
```

**Calling function**

```
var searchUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" + "emre" + "&rpp=" + 5 + "&lang=en&callback=?";

searchThis(searchUrl);
```